# plotting a 2D dataset with different variable in thrree dimension

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a dataset. I want to plot it in 3D using graphics3D. Following is my code which I have tried:

```
datatest={{{10, 1, 1.15}, {100, 1, 1.15}, {300, 1, 1.24}}, {{0.02, 4,
    1.012}, {0.05, 4, 0.94}}, {{10, 2, 1.44}, {150, 2, 1.02}, {300, 2,
    1.011}}, {{0.05, 3, 1.15}, {0.15, 3, 1.01}, {0.35, 3, 1.14}}}

plot= Graphics3D[{{Red, 
   Polygon[{{-50, 0, 0.1}, {-50, 5, 0}, {320, 5, 0}, {320, 0, 
      0}}]}, {EdgeForm[None], 
   Table[Polygon[i, 
     VertexColors -> Map[Blend[{Blue, White}, #] &, i[[All, 3]]]], {i,
      datatest}]}}, Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> Large, 
 BoxRatios -> {0.65, 1.5, .1}, Boxed -> False, Background -> Black, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 2.5, 1}]
```

But I could not visualize all the data, I can only view only two of the dataset.
On addition I need two things:

1. I need to scale the data along the axis
2. I need to assign y axis (i.e. 1,2,3,4) in the dataset as "A","B","C","D" i.e. for 1 it will be A and so on along the y axis.

How can I do these on it?

Comment: (1) the list with `y= 4` contains only two points and (2) the list with `y = 3` is too small to be visible unless you increase image size.

Comment: yes, I  can understand the issue, but htese are experimental dataset. I can neither increase the datapoint for y=4 nor can increase the data value, So has there any other option?

Comment: replace `Polygon[i,...]` with `If[Length@i < 3, Line, Polygon][i,...]`?

Comment: its working, however may be due to small x value for y=3 and y=4, the datasets  are not visualised clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You could display the datasets as polygons that extend down to z=0.

```
dat = Join[#, {{#[[-1, 1]], #[[-1, 2]], 0}, {#[[1, 1]], #[[-1, 2]], 
       0}}] & /@ datatest;
Graphics3D[{{Red, 
   Polygon[{{-50, 0, 0.1}, {-50, 5, 0}, {320, 5, 0}, {320, 0, 
      0}}]}, {(*EdgeForm[None]*)
   Table[Polygon[i, 
     VertexColors -> Map[Blend[{Blue, White}, #] &, i[[All, 3]]]], {i,
      dat}]}}, Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> Large, 
 BoxRatios -> {0.65, 1.5, .1}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 2.5, 1}, Axes -> True, 
 Ticks -> {None, {{1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}}, None}]
```

[image]